# Is Xcode 5 an appropriate IDE for Fortran (gfortran) on OS X 10.9?

Tags: ide, xcode5, fortran, indentation

I have a working install of "gfortran" on "OS X 10.9". I am trying to work with "xcode 5.1.1", but the first experiences do not seem promising:
It recognizes that the code is **F90** but the behavior of the editor seems stupid - it does not even indent the code when asked.

Is this because my project is badly configured (it surely is) or is "xcode 5" unable to help developing in Fortran anyway ? (I found answers on the web regarding older versions suggesting that it is not appropriate, but then why is "xcode 5" recognizing **F77** and **F90** ?)
If "xcode" is inappropriate, other "IDE" suggestions for "gfortran" on "OS X"?

Thanks

Comment: Emacs has a Fortran mode and runs on all operating systems. I use Epsilon, a commercial Emacs-like editor.

Comment: Textmate and Sublime Text are my two suggestions.

Comment: You might try [Ftran Project Builder](http://www.nocturnalaviationsoftware.com) which is a commercial program but reasonably priced. Xcode had never proper Fortran support.